# Show for arbitrary $c_1,c_2 \in R$, $(c_1 L_1+c_2L_2)$ is a linear operator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two linear operators (well-defined on smooth functions in $R^n$). Show for arbitrary $c_1,c_2 \in R$, $(c_1 L_1+c_2L_2)$ is a linear operator.

For this problem, will I apply simply the superposition principle, along with the definition of linear map to do so right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By superposition principle, we have to verify $F(x_1+x_2)=F(x_1)+F(x_2)$ and $F(ax)=aF(x)$ for a be any scalar.

We only need to show that

$(v_1 L_1+c_2 L_2)(u+v)=(c_1L_1+c_2L_2)(u)+(c_1L_1+c_2L_2)(v)$

$((c_1L_1+c_2L_2)(cu)=c(c_1L_1+c_2L_2)(u)$